# Responsive wide image to fit vertically - Bootstrap

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, responsive-design

Bootstrap [carousel](http://getbootstrap.com/examples/carousel/) items can fit the vertical screen of a mobile device. but my images are wide and they won't scale nicely on mobile with this code:

**HTML:**

```
<div class="item">
  <img class="First-slide" src="images/bg01.jpg" alt="First slide">

</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
.carousel .item {
  height: 500px;
  background-color: #777;
}
.carousel-inner > .item > img {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  min-width: 100%;
  height: 500px;
}
```

How can I use CSS to show only part of the image (middle / left / right - like this [visual example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TyeR3.jpg)) for mobile vertical view?

Comment: want like this ? https://jsfiddle.net/td67sdas/2/

Answer (score 0):

Use `object-fit:cover` to have the best auto fit adjustment (100% area fill, keeping the aspect ratio and cropping when/if necessary). It demands a cointainer with `overflow:hidden`. You'll also need to add `position:relative` on the container since you're using a image with absolute position.

```
.carousel .item {
  height: 500px;
  background-color: #777;
  object-fit: cover;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: relative;
}
```

Comment: object-fit is not supported in any version of IE and Edge tho, could be a bit dangerous to use that.